# Xamarin Forms - Issue with Swipe to Delete on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

So I implemented swipe to delete functionality for iOS and long tap to delete for Android, everything works fine except - on iOS after swiping a cell and clicking delete button I am displaying Alert to confirm if user wants to delete item# XYZ, when alerts pops up another cell gets swiped. 
Any suggestions how to fix it?

XAML:

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=ListPage}}"
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

ViewModel (when delete command is called):

```
string Msg = string.Format("Delete item {0}?", selectedItem.ItemNumber); 
var answer = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(App.ResourceContainer.GetString("Confirmation_Message"),
Msg,
App.ResourceContainer.GetString("Yes"),
App.ResourceContainer.GetString("No"));
```